# Algorithm Time Complexity Analysis (for loop with inner while loop)

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, time-complexity

Here's the code I've implemented in a nutshell. The for loop should have a complexity of O(n). I just can't figure out the time complexity of the inner while loop.

```
int x,n;     // Inputted by the user.
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    int done=0;
    if (Condition)
    {

        while (done < x)
        {
            done++;     // Based on a lot of operations
        }
    }
}
```

I can post the whole code if you want. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The __overall__ inner loop complexity is O(x). But since you do not reset `done` to 0 the `x` times that the _"inner operations"_ are run get done all over the outer loop. In the end, these operations are only executed `x` times.

Comment: @Rerito I made a mistake sorry. The done is reset to zero every for loop iteration.

Comment: Then, it gets run each time `Condition` is triggered, not just the first time. The inner loop complexity stays O(x) (taking the number of times your operations are run as a metrics)

Comment: @Rerito Would the overall complexity be O(xn) in this case?

Comment: The inner loop complexity is O(x). Once combined with the outer loop, you get a worst-case complexity of O(xn).

Comment: Time complexity is at most O(nx). Since we dont know what 'Condition' is we cant tell more accurately.

Comment: @piotrekg2 Exactly. If, for instance, `Condition` is `!(i & (i-1))`, the inner loop will only run `floor(ln2(n)) + 1` times, causing the overall complexity to be O(x.ln(n))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the complexity is measured by studying the number of times the program will run the operations of the inner loop.

Each time `Condition` is triggered, the inner loop runs `x` times. Thus the *inner loop* complexity is O(x).

This loop can run **at most** `n` times. This provides you an overall *worst-case* complexity of O(x.n).

Having additional knowledge about `Condition` can get you a more precise analysis. You may be able to compute *average complexity* for example.

As an example : let `Condition` be `!(i & (i-1))`. This is **true** if and only if `i` is either 0 or a power of 2. In this case, your loop would get run exactly `E(ln2(n)) + 2` times (`E(.)` being the integer part function). In the end, the overall complexity *knowing* this becomes O(x.ln(n))